# How to calculate predictive performance in this search-based algorithm?

Tags: analytics, precision, precision-recall, predictive

I am developing a search algorithm which looks at lines of text and identifies terms of intrest. Once completed, these terms are compared with a gold standard. Sample results look like this:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5yqQ2.png)

What I dont understand is how to calculate the predictive performance of my solution.
from the above example, I can tell that True positives -> B and FP -> C.

Bu with the above data, we cannot really have a measure of false negative or true negative can we?

if so, we cant calculate any performance metric other than precision?